# Unable to practice Sql Injection (blind) on DVWA 1.10

Tags: sql-injection

I am practicing for Security Testing. I came across DVWA and I started practicing for Sql Injection. I was doing fine till I started with SQL Injection (blind). No matter which query I try I am not getting the desired result.
For eg :

`1' and 1=0 union select null,table_name from information_schema.tables#`

simply returns ***User ID exists in the database.***

I have set the DVWA Security to Low. Also made sure there are no errors on setup page of the application under **Setup Check** section.

Following are environment details:

Operating system: Windows

Backend database: MySQL

PHP version: 5.6.16

Comment: What is your question? And what has that to do with PHP?

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is here and the behavior is expected

https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA/issues/12

Someone complained of the opposite behavior and the developer agreed, and a contributor named g0tm1lk [fixed](https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA/pull/35) it. He made the exercise really "blind" and we have to use blind injection methods to test the vulnerability.

> Showing the SQL error messages to the user is just: a SQL injection vuln + a misconfiguration issue.
>
> A blind SQL injection might occur when the columns of the results returned by a query are not shown to the user. However, the user can tell somehow if the query returned any records or none.
>   E.g.: Suppose the url "http://www.example.com/user?id=USER_ID" returns:
>
> 200 if USER_ID exists
>
> 404 if USER_ID not exists
>
> But it won't show any information from the query results (e.g. username, address, phone, etc)
>
> If the page is vulnerable to SQLi [blind], an attacker won't be able get info from the DB printed in the result page, but he might be able to infer it by asking yes/no questions.